# Ajustar el contenido un reporte generado con FPDF

Tags: php, mysql, sql, fpdf

un saludo, estoy generando un reporte con FPDF en PHP

```
//Solicitando la conexion con la BD
require 'conexion.php';
//Efectuando la consulta de las vista
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM diferencias ORDER BY falla";
//Almaceando el resultado de la consulta en una variable
$resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);

// Creación del objeto de la clase heredada
$pdf = new PDF('L','mm','A4');//Indicando formato horizontal del reporte
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 8);

//Encabezados de la tabla
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', 'B', 8);//Colocando letras en negritas
$pdf->Cell(28, 10, 'Service Tag', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
$pdf->Cell(50, 10, 'Usuario', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
$pdf->Cell(65, 10, 'Diferencia 1', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
$pdf->Cell(65, 10, 'Diferencia 2', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
$pdf->Cell(65, 10, 'Falla', 1, 1, 'C', 0);
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 8);//Devolviendo valores de letra
```

Mi problema concreto esta aqui, algunos datos de la columna falla son demasiado amplios, quisiera saber si existe una forma de que se ajusten las letras al tamaño asignado de la celda

```
//Ciclo para recorrer la tabla e insertar registros en la tabla
$a=0;
while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    //Ancho alto,borde,salto de linea justificacion relleno
    //$pdf->Cell(15,10, utf8_decode($row['consecutivo']), 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(28,10, utf8_decode($row['servicetag']), 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(50,10, utf8_decode($row['usuario']), 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(65,10, utf8_decode($row['dif1']), 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(65,10, utf8_decode($row['dif2']), 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(65,10, utf8_decode($row['falla']), 1, 1, 'C', 0);
    $a=$a+1;
```

}

Ya que cuando efectuó el reporte se ve así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FPDF` soporta la característica `multicell`, entonces, en lugar de hacer esto:

```
$pdf->Cell(65,10, utf8_decode($row['falla']), 1, 1, 'C', 0);
```

Haz esto:

```
$pdf->multiCell(65,10,utf8_decode($row['falla']), 1, 1);
```

Y con ello el alto de la celda se ajustará a la cantidad de texto que contenga.

Comment: Me funciono perfecto, pero como indico el salto de línea ya que ahora me lo enlisto todo hacia abajo

Comment: La librería es un poco compleja para maquetar, pero nada que no se pueda resolver [leyendo la documentación oficial](http://www.fpdf.org/). Te recomiendo usar [`TCPDF`](https://tcpdf.org/), la cual permite maquetar tablas como si estuvieses haciéndolo en `HTML` y permite también la salida en navegador, descargar el archivo o almacenarlo en alguna ruta. Para mí personalmente, es mucho más simple de entender que `FPDF`